# Tkinter: windows without title bar but resizable

Tags: python, resize, tkinter, tk-toolkit, titlebar

What I know is if I want to create a window without title bar, I can write

```
    root = Tk()
    ........
    root.overrideredirect(1)
```

But I would also like the window to be resizable. Is there any solution?

(FYI: I am working on Windows machine, although I am not sure if it really matters. It will be perfect if there is OS-independent solution, but I am happy if there is at least a solution for Windows first.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is, the window *is* resizable, but when you turn on `overrideredirect` you lose any sort of header or edge that you can grab in order to resize the window. The only solution is to implement resizing yourself. You can add your own borders, or add mouse bindings that work when the mouse is near an edge.

This answer shows how to move such a window: [Python/Tkinter: Mouse drag a window without borders, eg. overridedirect(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4055267/7432)

Here's a short example that illustrates resizing. It has only barely been tested on OSX but should work on any platform. It uses python2, though it should work with python3 just by changing the import statements.

```
import Tkinter as tk
import ttk

class Example(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.floater = FloatingWindow(self)

class FloatingWindow(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.overrideredirect(True)
        self.wm_geometry("400x400")

        self.label = tk.Label(self, text="Grab the lower-right corner to resize")
        self.label.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

        self.grip = ttk.Sizegrip(self)
        self.grip.place(relx=1.0, rely=1.0, anchor="se")
        self.grip.lift(self.label)
        self.grip.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.OnMotion)


    def OnMotion(self, event):
        x1 = self.winfo_pointerx()
        y1 = self.winfo_pointery()
        x0 = self.winfo_rootx()
        y0 = self.winfo_rooty()
        self.geometry("%sx%s" % ((x1-x0),(y1-y0)))
        return

app=Example()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Straightforward modifications allow windows that are resizable in only one direction on the Mac, where owing to some Tk bug, `win.resizable(False,True)` and `win.resizable(True, False)` create windows resizable in both directions.

Answer (score 1):

An extended working example of @Bryan's solution can be found here:

```
import tkinter as tk


class FloatingWindow(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.overrideredirect(True)
        self.center()

        self.label = tk.Label(self, text="Grab one of the blue")
        self.label.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

        self.grip_se = tk.Label(self,bg='blue')
        self.grip_se.place(relx=1.0, rely=1.0, anchor="se")
        self.grip_se.bind("<B1-Motion>",lambda e, mode='se':self.OnMotion(e,mode))

        self.grip_e = tk.Label(self,bg='green')
        self.grip_e.place(relx=1.0, rely=0.5, anchor="e")
        self.grip_e.bind("<B1-Motion>",lambda e, mode='e':self.OnMotion(e,mode))
        
        self.grip_ne = tk.Label(self,bg='blue')
        self.grip_ne.place(relx=1.0, rely=0, anchor="ne")
        self.grip_ne.bind("<B1-Motion>",lambda e, mode='ne':self.OnMotion(e,mode))

        self.grip_n = tk.Label(self,bg='green')
        self.grip_n.place(relx=0.5, rely=0, anchor="n")
        self.grip_n.bind("<B1-Motion>",lambda e, mode='n':self.OnMotion(e,mode))

        self.grip_nw = tk.Label(self,bg='blue')
        self.grip_nw.place(relx=0, rely=0, anchor="nw")
        self.grip_nw.bind("<B1-Motion>",lambda e, mode='nw':self.OnMotion(e,mode))

        self.grip_w = tk.Label(self,bg='green')
        self.grip_w.place(relx=0, rely=0.5, anchor="w")
        self.grip_w.bind("<B1-Motion>",lambda e, mode='w':self.OnMotion(e,mode))

        self.grip_sw = tk.Label(self,bg='blue')
        self.grip_sw.place(relx=0, rely=1, anchor="sw")
        self.grip_sw.bind("<B1-Motion>",lambda e, mode='sw':self.OnMotion(e,mode))

        self.grip_s = tk.Label(self,bg='green')
        self.grip_s.place(relx=0.5, rely=1, anchor="s")
        self.grip_s.bind("<B1-Motion>",lambda e, mode='s':self.OnMotion(e,mode))

    def OnMotion(self, event, mode):
        abs_x = self.winfo_pointerx() - self.winfo_rootx()
        abs_y = self.winfo_pointery() - self.winfo_rooty()
        width = self.winfo_width()
        height= self.winfo_height()
        x = self.winfo_rootx()
        y = self.winfo_rooty()
        
        if mode == 'se' and abs_x >0 and abs_y >0:
                self.geometry("%sx%s" % (abs_x,abs_y)
                              )
                
        if mode == 'e':
            if height >0 and abs_x >0:
                self.geometry("%sx%s" % (abs_x,height)
                              )
        if mode == 'ne' and abs_x >0:
                y = y+abs_y
                height = height-abs_y
                if height >0:
                    self.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (abs_x,height,
                                                   x,y))
        if mode == 'n':
            height=height-abs_y
            y = y+abs_y
            if height >0 and width >0:
                self.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (width,height,
                                               x,y))
            
        if mode == 'nw':
            width = width-abs_x
            height=height-abs_y
            x = x+abs_x
            y = y+abs_y
            if height >0 and width >0:
                self.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (width,height,
                                               x,y))
        if mode == 'w':
            width = width-abs_x
            x = x+abs_x
            if height >0 and width >0:
                self.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (width,height,
                                               x,y))
        if mode == 'sw':
            width = width-abs_x
            height=height-(height-abs_y)
            x = x+abs_x
            if height >0 and width >0:
                self.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (width,height,
                                               x,y))
        if mode == 's':
            height=height-(height-abs_y)
            if height >0 and width >0:
                self.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (width,height,
                                               x,y))
            
        
    def center(self):
        width = 300
        height = 300
        screen_width = self.winfo_screenwidth()
        screen_height = self.winfo_screenheight()
        x_coordinate = (screen_width/2) - (width/2)
        y_coordinate = (screen_height/2) - (height/2)

        self.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (width, height,
                                       x_coordinate, y_coordinate))

app=FloatingWindow()
app.mainloop()
```

Output:

[image]

If someone know how to get rid of the performance issues, please answer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64066592/tkinter-custom-resize-event-after-overrideredirect1).