# How to make Tkinter window stationary

Tags: python, tkinter

I was trying to run a Thread for some time.So, if I try to reposition the Tkinter window I get

```
Fatal Python error: PyEval_RestoreThread: NULL tstate
Python runtime state: initialized
```

But then I realized if I didn't reposition that window. It was working fine.

**Some More Details:** To reposition a window, we manually do it by dragging/moving the title bar of the Window Hence Overdirected(True) removes the Title Bar. I want to know if it's possible to have the default Title Bar but it performs the same action as `Overdirected(True)`

**Edit:** I wanted to use the same feature as `overdirected(True)` but I still need the title bar

I tried to search for some pre questions but most of them were based on resizeable things.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is by binding the `configure` **event** and give a specific position that will be forced by the `geometry` method of the `Toplevel`:

```py
import tkinter as tk
    
def stay(event):
    my_spot = 100,100
    root.geometry("+%d+%d" % (my_spot))
    
root=tk.Tk()
root.bind('<Configure>', stay)
    
root.mainloop()
```

Another way, with addition problems, to solve the problem I to set the `overrideredirect` flag to `True`:

```py
import tkinter as tk
    
root=tk.Tk()
root.geometry("+%d+%d" % (100,100))
root.overrideredirect(1)
    
root.mainloop()
```

> Some More Details: To reposition it we manually do it by
> dragging/moving the title bar of the Window so Overdirected(True)
> removes the Title Bar So I want to know if it's possible to have the
> default Title Bar but it doesn't respond to event that can resize the
> whole window

To achive that, you can use the built-in method `resizable`:

```py
import tkinter as tk
    
root=tk.Tk()
root.resizable(False, False)
    
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The first one worked according to the title but it calls `Configure` twice (Mouse drag event and for restoring it) so that thread problem still exists but `Overdirected` works as expected but again it doesn't allow me to use the Title bar. So I just need to unbind the event that causes the window to resize

Comment: @RahulARanger can you give me some more informations? Im confused right now. What is the exact problem over there?

Comment: sorry for providing less info. I edited the Question. Please Check. Repositioning can freeze an app when the app has some 5-6 active threads or at least two threads performing heavy tasks. So I want to customize the Overdirected(True) without losing the default title bar

Comment: I updated as well. Is this what you want to achive?

Comment: I assume you are new to `tkinter` I had provide a small overview of the geometry managment of tkinter [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63536505/how-do-i-organize-my-tkinter-appllication/63536506#63536506)

Comment: It's Not size-based tho. It's ok, I will use a customized title bar along with `Overdirected(True) `.

Comment: May I can give you a hint there, [how to resize after overrideredirect](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64077176/13629335)