# Moving an overrideredirected top Level window well allowing for minimization

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Good Afternoon,

I've been attempting to implement the script from this page:
[Tkinter: Mouse drag a window without borders, eg. overridedirect(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4055267/tkinter-mouse-drag-a-window-without-borders-eg-overridedirect1)

To work with my tkinter top Level window.
This is how my tkinter window is initialized:

```
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        tkinter.Tk.__init__(self, master)
```

I then hide the root window and start up a top level window. Which i'm doing so that I can currently minimize and re-open the top level window.

```
    #Hide Root
    self.attributes("-alpha",0.0)
    self.attributes("-topmost", True)

    #Top Level Window
    top_level = tkinter.Toplevel(self)
    top_level.geometry("600x300")
    top_level.overrideredirect(True)
    top_level.config(bg="#1e1e1e")
```

Now I try and get the window to move using this chunk of code here from the page listed above. (I've changed some of the variables to match my window)

```
    top_level.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", top_level.StartMove)
    top_level.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", top_level.StopMove)
    top_level.bind("<B1-Motion>", top_level.OnMotion)

def StartMove(top_level, event):
    top_level.x = event.x
    top_level.y = event.y

def StopMove(top_level, event):
    top_level.x = None
    top_level.y = None

def OnMotion(top_level, event):
    deltax = event.x - top_level.x
    deltay = event.y - top_level.y
    x = top_level.winfo_x() + deltax
    y = top_level.winfo_y() + deltay
    top_level.geometry("+%s+%s" % (x, y))
```

This is the error that I receive:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/Programs/TestGUI/script_gui.py", line 2, in <module>
    import authenticator
  File "E:\Programs\TestGUI\authenticator.py", line 148, in <module>
    root = Win()
  File "E:\Programs\TestGUI\authenticator.py", line 127, in __init__
    top_level.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", top_level.StartMove)
AttributeError: 'Toplevel' object has no attribute 'StartMove'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as this is one of the last things I need to do to finish this project.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the error message, you have a class name `Win` which is derived from `tkinter.Tk`.  So all the functions in the posted code are inside that class.

Then the three lines:

```
top_level.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", top_level.StartMove)
top_level.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", top_level.StopMove)
top_level.bind("<B1-Motion>", top_level.OnMotion)
```

should be changed to:

```
self.top_level.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", self.StartMove)
self.top_level.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.StopMove)
self.top_level.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.OnMotion)
```

`top_level` should be better an instance variable of the class so that it can be accessed by other class methods:

```
self.top_level = tkinter.Toplevel(self)
self.top_level.geometry('600x300')
self.top_level.overrideredirect(1)
self.top_level.config(bg='#1e1e1e')
```

Also normally the name of the first argument of class methods `StartMove()`, `StopMove()` and `OnMotion()` is `self`.  And those functions should be modified to cater the change of `top_level` from local variable to instance variable:

```
def StartMove(self, event):
    self.top_level.x = event.x
    self.top_level.y = event.y

def StopMove(self, event):
    self.top_level.x = self.top_level.y = None

def OnMotion(self, event):
    deltax = event.x - self.top_level.x
    deltay = event.y - self.top_level.y
    x = self.top_level.winfo_x() + deltax
    y = self.top_level.winfo_y() + deltay
    self.top_level.geometry('+%s+%s' % (x, y))
```

Below is the definition of the class `Win`:

```
class Win(tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tkinter.Tk.__init__(self)
        #Hide Root
        self.attributes('-alpha', 0.0)
        self.attributes('-topmost', 1)

        #Top Level Window
        self.top_level = tkinter.Toplevel(self)
        self.top_level.geometry('600x300')
        self.top_level.overrideredirect(1)
        self.top_level.config(bg='#1e1e1e')
        self.top_level.bind('<ButtonPress-1>', self.StartMove)
        self.top_level.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', self.StopMove)
        self.top_level.bind('<B1-Motion>', self.OnMotion)

    def StartMove(self, event):
        self.top_level.x = event.x
        self.top_level.y = event.y

    def StopMove(self, event):
        self.top_level.x = self.top_level.y = None

    def OnMotion(self, event):
        deltax = event.x - self.top_level.x
        deltay = event.y - self.top_level.y
        x = self.top_level.winfo_x() + deltax
        y = self.top_level.winfo_y() + deltay
        self.top_level.geometry('+%s+%s' % (x, y))
```

Comment: Thank you for this very in-depth and explained answer. This worked like a charm!