# Custom title bar and close button Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, titlebar

I found this code on stackoverflow:

```
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()
root.overrideredirect(True) # turns off title bar, geometry
root.geometry('400x100+200+200') # set new geometry

# make a frame for the title bar
title_bar = Frame(root, bg='#2e2e2e', relief='raised', bd=2,highlightthickness=0)

# put a close button on the title bar
close_button = Button(title_bar, text='X', command=root.destroy,bg="#2e2e2e",padx=2,pady=2,activebackground='red',bd=0,font="bold",fg='white',highlightthickness=0)

# a canvas for the main area of the window
window = Canvas(root, bg='#2e2e2e',highlightthickness=0)

# pack the widgets
title_bar.pack(expand=1, fill=X)
close_button.pack(side=RIGHT)
window.pack(expand=1, fill=BOTH)
xwin=None
ywin=None
# bind title bar motion to the move window function

def move_window(event):
    root.geometry('+{0}+{1}'.format(event.x_root, event.y_root))
def change_on_hovering(event):
    global close_button
    close_button['bg']='red'
def return_to_normalstate(event):
    global close_button
    close_button['bg']='#2e2e2e'


title_bar.bind('<B1-Motion>', move_window)
close_button.bind('<Enter>',change_on_hovering)
close_button.bind('<Leave>',return_to_normalstate)
root.mainloop()
```

[image: screen of the result]

The problem being that the movement of the window is very weird, is there a way to fix it by changing the code?

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4055612/11024053

Comment: Perfect thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FIX:

```
from tkinter import *
from webbrowser import *

root=Tk()
root.overrideredirect(True) # turns off title bar, geometry
root.geometry('400x100+200+200') # set new geometry
root.attributes('-topmost', True)

lastClickX = 0
lastClickY = 0

def SaveLastClickPos(event):
    global lastClickX, lastClickY
    lastClickX = event.x
    lastClickY = event.y

def Dragging(event):
    x, y = event.x - lastClickX + root.winfo_x(), event.y - lastClickY + root.winfo_y()
    root.geometry("+%s+%s" % (x , y))

# make a frame for the title bar
title_bar = Frame(root, bg='#2e2e2e', relief='raised', bd=2,highlightthickness=0)

# put a close button on the title bar
close_button = Button(title_bar, text='X', command=root.destroy,bg="#2e2e2e",padx=2,pady=2,activebackground='red',bd=0,font="bold",fg='white',highlightthickness=0)

window = Canvas(root, bg='#2e2e2e',highlightthickness=0)

# pack the widgets
title_bar.pack(expand=1, fill=X)
close_button.pack(side=RIGHT)
window.pack(expand=1, fill=BOTH)

title_bar.bind('<Button-1>', SaveLastClickPos)
title_bar.bind('<B1-Motion>', Dragging)
root.mainloop()
```